# Create two-index dictionary from three-column pandas df?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary, multi-index

I'm trying to take a pandas df with three columns of stock return data - `date`, `ticker`, and `total_return` - and create a dictionary with `date` and `ticker` as the two keys and `total_return` as the value.

So, far I can get the dictionary to have the two keys, but the `total_return` column turns into a third key which is not what I need.

**Example:** Starting with this df,

```
date    ticker  total_return
0   2009-10-02  AIR 0.024265
1   2009-10-05  AIR 0.010478
2   2009-10-06  AIR 0.020739
3   2009-10-07  AIR -0.029594
4   2009-10-08  AIR 0.021848
```

I can run:

`daily_dict_input.set_index(['date','ticker']).stack().to_dict()`

which returns the dict:

```
{(datetime.date(2009, 10, 2), 'AIR', 'total_return'): 0.02426504899673332,
 (datetime.date(2009, 10, 5), 'AIR', 'total_return'): 0.010478359908883794,
 (datetime.date(2009, 10, 6), 'AIR', 'total_return'): 0.020739404869251743,
 (datetime.date(2009, 10, 7), 'AIR', 'total_return'): -0.02959363957597183,
 (datetime.date(2009, 10, 8), 'AIR', 'total_return'): 0.02184797451069631}
```

which is close, but I don't want `total_return` to also be a key. I would just like the dictionary to look like:

```
{(datetime.date(2009, 10, 2), 'AIR'): 0.02426504899673332,
 (datetime.date(2009, 10, 5), 'AIR'): 0.010478359908883794,
 (datetime.date(2009, 10, 6), 'AIR'): 0.020739404869251743,
 (datetime.date(2009, 10, 7), 'AIR'): -0.02959363957597183,
 (datetime.date(2009, 10, 8), 'AIR'): 0.02184797451069631}
```

**Question:** How can I remove the `total_return` key when I create the dictionary from the two-index pandas df so I just have a `[date,ticker]total_return` format for my dictionary?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```py
out = df.set_index(['date', 'ticker'])['total_return'].to_dict()
print(out)
```

Prints:

```
{
 ('2009-10-02', 'AIR'): 0.024265, 
 ('2009-10-05', 'AIR'): 0.010478, 
 ('2009-10-06', 'AIR'): 0.020739, 
 ('2009-10-07', 'AIR'): -0.029594, 
 ('2009-10-08', 'AIR'): 0.021848
}
```